# Overriding fetch in multiple spine models

Tags: coffeescript, spine.js

I need to override Spine's `@fetch()` method in all of my Spine models. Currently I have code duplication as follows:

```
TastypieEndpointMixin =
    fromJSON: (data) ->
        return unless data
        return Spine.Model.fromJSON(data.objects)

class App.models.Position extends Spine.Model
    @configure 'Position', 'code', 'name'
    @extend Spine.Model.Ajax
    @extend TastypieEndpointMixin
    @url: '/api/v1/position/?format=json'

    validate: ->
        'code is required' unless @code

    @fetch: ->
        defer = $.Deferred()
        @one "refresh", ->
            defer.resolve()
        super
        return defer


class App.models.Player extends Spine.Model
    @configure 'Player', 'first_name', 'last_name', ...
    @extend Spine.Model.Ajax
    @extend TastypieEndpointMixin
    @url: '/api/v1/player/?format=json'

    @fetch: ->
        defer = $.Deferred()
        @one "refresh", ->
            defer.resolve()
        super
        return defer
```

My question is: How can I create some form of parent class which contains `@fetch()`?

I know this should be a simple problem to solve. I have tried many options (including extending `Spine.Model` and `Spine.Model.Ajax`), but nothing works and I cannot seem to get my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the exact same problem:

```
class BasicModel extends Spine.Model

  @fetch: ->
    defer = $.Deferred()
    @one "refresh", ->
      defer.resolve()        
    super
    defer

class App.models.Player extends BasicModel

  #This class now has the fetch() function from the BasisModel
```

Of course you can put a lot of useful functions in the BasicModel which will be available in all your other models.